# C - formatting MAC address

Tags: c, formatting

I am currently working with parsing some MAC addresses. I am given an output that does not include leading zeros (like so).

```
char* host = "0:25:25:0:25:25";
```

and I would like to format it like so

```
char* host = "00:25:25:00:25:25";
```

What would be the easiest way to go about this?

For those wondering, I am using the libpcap library.

Comment: replace ":0:" with :00:", with loop.

Comment: This would require multiple replacement passes to deal with the values 1..f. Reformatting could still be less efficient, but would be a more consistent approach.

Comment: @Guy, don't forget to handle the first and last element, too.

Answer (score 4):

I may be missing something in the question. Assuming you know it is a valid MAC, and the input string is thus parsable, have you considered something as simple as:

```
char* host1 = "0:25:25:0:AB:25";
char *host2 = "0:1:02:3:0a:B";
char result[19];
int a,b,c,d,e,f;

// the question sample
if (sscanf(host1, "%x:%x:%x:%x:%x:%x", &a,&b,&c,&d,&e, &f) == 6)
    sprintf(result, "%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X", a,b,c,d,e,f);
printf("host1: %s\n", result);

// a more daunting sample
if (sscanf(host2, "%x:%x:%x:%x:%x:%x", &a,&b,&c,&d,&e, &f) == 6)
    sprintf(result, "%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X", a,b,c,d,e,f);
printf("host2: %s\n", result);
```

**Output**

```
host1: 00:25:25:00:AB:25
host2: 00:01:02:03:0A:0B
```

Obviously for the ultra-paranoid you would want to make sure `a-f` are all < 255, which is probably preferable. The fundamental reasons I prefer this where performance isn't a critical issue are the *many* things you may not be considering in your question. It handles all of

1. Lead values of `"n:"`, where `n` is *any* hex digit; not just zero. Examples: `"5:"`, `"0:"`
2. Mid values of `":n:"`, again under the same conditions as (1) above. Examples: `":A:"`, `":0:"`
3. Tail values of `":n"`. once more, under the same conditions as (1) above. Examples: `":b"`, `":0"`
4. Hex-digit agnostic when reading; it works with both upper and lower case digit chars.
5. Most important, does nothing (except upper-case the hex values) if your input string is already properly formatted.

Comment: @icepack its a lot of CPU work for what is affectively just slipping some zeros in. obivously it would be better to walk the input and output buffers, just slipping in the extra `0` where needed. but in a non-peformance critical pinch, it works just ok.  I'm drafting an alternate now.

Comment: I like this solution, no need to make C a lower language than it already is, if not really necessary

Answer (score 0):

Roughly like this:
Allocate an output string to hold the reformatted MAC address.
Iterate over the input string and use `strtok` with `:` delimiter. In each iteration convert the beginning of the string (2 bytes) into a numerical value (e.g., with `atoi`). If the result < 16 (i.e., < 0x10), set `"0"` into the output string at current position and the result in hex at the following position; otherwise copy the 2 bytes of input string. Append `:` to the output string. Continue till end of the input.

Comment: This is not much faster than the WhozCraig response, and can really obscure the intent.

The obviously faster solution would be to unpack the binary MAC using just the output portion of the fragment (with a hex-value lookup table if necessary) to avoid the parsing hit.

Comment: @Pekka I wrote this before WhozCraig wrote his answer; it doesn't pretend to be faster or anything else. The answer is, however, correct. I find the downvote somewhat strange

Comment: I had not noted the timing, but felt that de-emphasising the less efficient response would help to direct readers to the more appropriate one.

Comment: @Pekka this is the most straightforward answer. It's correct, self-explanatory and it's performance is satisfactory for most cases