# C++ convert string date (1/4/2000) to int date (20000104)

Tags: c++, string, date, data-conversion

I can write a function to parse the string date, but I feel like I am re-inventing the wheel here. Is there a faster, perhaps built in C++ way to get from a string date of this format: 1/4/2000 to a more easy to use int like 20000104?

Comment: A [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14534780/c-formatting-mac-address) has been asked recently.

Comment: 20000104 could be easy to compare or order but for any aritmetic...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you need your built-in C++ way to do validation as well, the "obvious" parse is:

```
int parseDate(const std::string &input) {
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
    if (std::sscanf(input.c_str(), "%d/%d/%d", &month, &day, &year) != 3) {
        // handle error
    } else {
        // check values to avoid int overflow if you can be bothered
        return 10000 * year + 100 * month + day;
    }
}
```

You can use stream extractors instead of `sscanf` if you want <s>to write several lines of code</s> type safety.

There's certainly nothing in the standard library to do the `10000 * year + 100 * month + day` for you. If you're not wedded to that exact value, you just want an integer in the correct order, then you could look at whether your platform has a function to tell you the so-called "Julian day".

Answer (score 2):

The standard library function is [`strptime()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strptime), not sure how "clean" that is considered to be in C++, though.

If you're okay with `strptime()`, here's how you would use it for your case:

```
struct tm when;

strptime("1/4/2000", "%m/%d/%y", &tm); // Note: should check return value.
const int sortable = 10000 * tm.tm_year + 100 * tm.tm_month + tm.tm_day;
```

Of course, you can use Boost if you want; the relevant corner seems to be [Posix Time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html).

Comment: I'm not familiar with strptime(), is it possible to provide an example that can handle my case so I (and others with similar question) can see how it works?

Comment: I think the relevant Boost documentation is [date_input_facet](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html#date_time.date_input_facet). Posix Time assumes that the input is already in ISO format, i.e. year first.

Comment: `strptime` has the exciting property that it's in Posix but not in standard C++ (or standard C). C++ has a locale category called `time_get` that parses the same formats, but I've never used it so I can't readily churn out an example.

Comment: this codes doesn't work, tm_year doesn't correctly get the year.